SVM Kernal the correct approach for classification problem?
I am working on a classification model that I will explain below and I wanted to get some insight on the optimal approach. I am currently experimenting with SKLearn and SVM Kernel as such svm.SVC(kernel='linear').
I work in a lab and I have x-ray devices that fail for different reasons such as: overheating, overcooling, running without proper boot time, etc. I have a dataset with thousands of runs along with a snapshot (system temp, time since boot, etc.) of the system and whether the run failed or succeeded. I want to make a model that will take as input a snapshot of the systems diagnostics (system temp, time since boot, etc.) upon failure and predict why the system failed. Output should be a list of the probability that each system attribute was the cause of failure. I read that SVM is almost a black box model and interoperability is hard.
I'd appreciate some advice on what I should look into and how I can achieve such a design.
